# limits definition exercise

Tags: real-analysis, limits

how to prove  ${ \lim_{x\to\infty} \sqrt{h_n}= \sqrt{a} }$  where  ${ \lim_{x\to\infty}h_n=a }$ and a${ \gt0 }$ with only rigorous definition limit: For all ε > 0 there exists a natural number N , such that if n ≥ N then |a_n − t| < ε. I have tried Cauchy inequality but couldn't proceed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: $$|\sqrt{h_n} - \sqrt{a}| = \frac{|h_n - a|}{\sqrt{h_n} + \sqrt{a}}.$$

When $n$ is large, the numerator is close to zero and the denominator is close to $2 \sqrt{a}$, so the left-hand side is also small. (This all needs to be made precise, though.)

Comment: thanks Sir for help